# Regex for valid WKT Linestrings (in BigQuery)?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, gis, wkt

So far I have the following:

```sql
 select WKT, column1, column2
  from table
 where REGEXP_CONTAINS(WKT, r"-?(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d*)?)") is true
```

This takes care of the majority of cases but I am still getting the following error:

`ST_GeogFromText failed: Linestring should have at least two unique points, but had 1`

How can I use `regex` to filter out *all* invalid LINESTRINGs in Google BigQuery? I can't use `ST_NUMPOINTS()` because it takes a `GEOGRAPHY` object and I can't convert the string to `GEOGRAPHY` if its invalid.

Edit: WKT LINESTRINGs have the following format: `LINESTRING (x1 y1, x2 y2, x3 y3, ..., xn yn)` where each `(xn, yn)` pair represents the nth Lat/Long pair.

Comment: For those uninformed among us: which structure does a `WKT` linestring have? Can you provide some samples?

Comment: Sure! I will edit the question accordingly, sorry about that.

Comment: So in summary: I am having some records which look like this (`LINESTRING (1.00 2.00)`) but they should have more than one pair of numbers (like this: `LINESTRING (1.00 2.00, 3.00 4.00)` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use REGEXP - it is unlikely to catch all problems. E.g. WKT might have latitude greater than 90 degrees, which causes a failure in ST_GeogFromText, but almost impossible to catch in REGEXP. Or you might have two identical points `LINESTRING (1 2, 1 2)` and that is also invalid LineString.

Use [SAFE prefix](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/syntax) instead, it causes the function to return NULL instead of failing query when the input is invalid. That gives you exact validation!

```
select SAFE.ST_GeogFromText('foo')
NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below extension of your original regexp

```
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(WKT, r'LINESTRING \((?:(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d*)?) (?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d*)?)(?:, |\))){2,}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Turns out using the `SAFE` prefix is more robust for my use case. Also in case anyone doesn't have that option, I found that using `LINESTRING\s\((?:\-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?\s\-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\,\s?\-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?\s\-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?)+\)` was more robust anyway as it allows the capture of possible values like: `LINESTRING (-10.00002 111.222222,2 -4,1.646373 -20.555)`.

Comment: sure, no problem. it was hard to imaging for me that you didn't know about SAFE prefix. so I assumed you specifically looking for regexp option. and yes - looks like I missed `-?` to address negative values :o)